# How to change string in multimap

Tags: c++, c++11

I have multimap:

```
multimap<string, vector<object> > myMultimap;
```

and I need to change string in part of multimap that has been already created.

it->first = newString;

doesn't work....

Comment: The key of a map/set/.. is not mutable. Otherwise, you could mess with the class invariants. AFAIK, you have to extract the elements and insert them with a new key.

Comment: What @dyp said, and if you need to do this, there is an issue with your design.  I think you may be suffering from the XY problem (you're asking about X, but you mean to do Y).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to "change" the keys of all elements with that key:

```
template<typename Key, typename ValueType, typename Compare,
         typename Allocator, typename FromKey, typename ToKey>
auto change_key(std::multimap<Key, ValueType, Compare, Allocator>& m,
                FromKey const& from_raw, ToKey const& to_raw)
-> typename std::multimap<Key, ValueType, Compare, Allocator>::iterator
{
    Key const& from = from_raw; // convert once only, not in each iteration
    Key const& to = to_raw;

    auto hint = m.lower_bound(to);
    auto const itsFrom = m.equal_range(from);
    for(auto cur = itsFrom.first; cur != itsFrom.second; ++cur)
    {
        hint = m.emplace_hint(hint, to, std::move(cur->second));
    }
    m.erase(itsFrom.first, itsFrom.second);
    return hint;
}
```

In C++1y, if the comparison function object is transparent, you might want to drop the explicit conversion to `from` and `to`.

I'm not quite sure if I used `lower_bound` correctly as a hint; the Standard (n3797) says the following about the hint `p` in Table 102 - Associative container requirements (in addition to container):

> The element is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to `p`.

and the complexity:

> logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if the element is inserted right before `p`

So we need the position *after* our insertion point; I'm not sure if the insertion point itself is a useful hint. To me, this seems to suggest using `upper_bound`, since that always returns a position with a key greater than the searched key; on the other hand I keep finding answers that suggest using `lower_bound` is the way to go.

Usage example:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct object
{
    int m;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, object const& p)
{
    return o << p.m;
}

template<typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, std::vector<V> const& v)
{
    for(auto const& e : v) o << e;
    return o;
}

template<typename K, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, std::multimap<K, V> const& m)
{
    for(auto const& p : m) o << "["<<p.first<<" : "<<p.second<<"], ";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    auto make_vector = [](int p) { return std::vector<object>{{p}}; };
    std::multimap<std::string, std::vector<object>> myMultimap =
    {{
          {"1st", make_vector(0)}
        , {"1st", make_vector(1)}
        , {"1st", make_vector(2)}
        , {"2nd", make_vector(3)}
        , {"2nd", make_vector(4)}
        , {"2nd", make_vector(5)}
        , {"3rd", make_vector(6)}
        , {"3rd", make_vector(7)}
        , {"3rd", make_vector(8)}
    }};

    std::cout << myMultimap;

    change_key(myMultimap, "2nd", "4th");

    std::cout << "\n\n" << myMultimap;
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'm not sure I understood the part "The identity_t puts from and to in a non-deduced context", I see what the issue is but not how this technique solve it. Is it idiomatic? Can you provide a link to some examples/documentation/GOTW/... about that? Thks

Comment: @Joky It's certainly not idiomatic and probably overcomplicated. I changed it to using local variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the key of the map/multimap, because it's a constant value. Another way is to find key you want replace, remove it and insert new value:

```
typedef multimap<string, vector<object> > Multimap;
Multimap myMultimap;
// ...
Multimap::iterator item_pos = myMultimap.find("some value");
if(item_pos != myMultimap.end())
{
    vector<object> key_value = item_pos->second;
    myMultimap.erase(item_pos);
    myMultimap.insert(Multimap::value_type("new value", key_value));
}
```

Comment: You should use move semantics, OP has C++11 support. Also, your inserting isn't optimal since it (semantically) requires searching the insertion point for every element with the original key.

Comment: Also, you only "change the key" of *one* element. Not sure if the OP wants that.

Comment: @dyp, yes, you are right. About move semantics - I'm currently stuck with old complier witout C++11 support:( And about really "correct" example(I'm talking about your answer - it's really good answer) - i decide that if user doesn't know about associative containers key's type, maybe it's not good idea to make an example with such thing as using template argument deduction fail ? Your example is good for all other users but not for questioner, isn't ? And, btw, your example is not optimal too. You need remove lower_bound and use current iterator as hint

Comment: Template argument deduction won't fail in my example just because of the `identity_t` trick. That disables deduction for the last two arguments. Anyway, I removed that part since, as I said, using local variables should be possible too. About the hint -- I'm not sure about the requirements here. See my updated answer. I changed it using your description.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just "change" a key like that, you have to create a new entry for the record, and erase the old one:

```
multimap<string, vector<object> > myMultimap;
...
myMultimap.insert(std::make_pair(newString, it->second));
myMultimap.erase(it);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

"I have a multimap" and,

"I need to change the key and not the data"

The answer is:

"You have chosen the wrong data structure - it's time to rethink the solution"